# min and max in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a huge amount of points data set. so i want to find min and max values from these points set. now i am using normal for loop for this purpose nice it is working but i want to know posibility to use opencv library since i wish to use this library. so plese any one help me. thanks

Comment: OpeNCV is a computer vision library, what makes you think it has improved functionality for finding the min/max elements of a set? You can't just pick a library and say "I want to use that to do this".

Comment: @GManNickG OpenCV offers a great deal of tools to work with big data sets, using hand-optimized assembly functions, SSE/NEON and GPU tools, that are usually much faster than the std or other math libraries.

Comment: The question is unclear: OP has a set of points (x,y coordinates) and then what is he looking for? Max x,y coordinates or max pixel value of an image in that coordinate? In which kind of container are the points stored? The answers here try to go in all directions. I believe this question is dangerous confused documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for OpenCV in this case: it's already in the standard library (`std::min_element` and `std::max_element`).

Comment: @Antonio: If there's anything in the question to suggest he would be using a Mat iterator, I can't find it. He says he has data, and is interested in using OpenCV, but I don't see anything to even suggest that he's already storing the data in a format defined by OpenCV.

Comment: You are totally right. I will delete my comment. I dropped here while navigating some minmax on cv::Mat questions, and also saw [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559146/min-and-max-in-opencv/5559302?noredirect=1#comment17135339_12693627) which dragged me in the wrong direction.

Comment: The question was unclear though: OP has a set of points (x,y coordinates) and then what is he looking for? Max x,y coordinates or max pixel value of an image in that coordinate? By the fact that he accepted this answer you would think the first, but it seems strange to me. I will vote for closing the question, it is bad documentation in this moment.

Comment: Note that the `cv::Mat()` iterators are very inefficient. *If* your data is image pixels and stored in a `cv::Mat` your better off using `cv::minMaxLoc()`

Answer (score 5):

There are several options.  Using OpenCV for this *may* give you an easy way to use SSE or other partially par

http://docs.opencv.org/search.html?q=minMax&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Some of those can use the GPU to help.  Of course, the GPU will only be faster if your data was already in the GPU.  Pushing data across the bus onto your video card just for this kind of search would be a net loss.

Comment: If the data is already in OpenCV's Mat format, or can be converted witohut data copy, this way will give a **huge, huge** speed boost over the std::max_element way. Like an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: broken link in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::max_element()` with a single channel cv::Mat like this:

`img = img / *max_element(img.begin<float>(), img.end<float>());`