# Matlab min equivalent in OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, min

I'm looking for an equivalent for the `min` function of Matlab in OpenCV, with this particular functionality (taken from [the official Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)):

> [M,I] = min(___) finds the indices of
>   the minimum values of A and returns
>   them in output vector I, using any of
>   the input arguments in the previous
>   syntaxes. If the minimum value occurs
>   more than once, then min returns the
>   index corresponding to the first
>   occurrence.

In my specific case, I have 2 images. I want to create a new image with the minimum value of each pixel (wrt those 2 images), and I need to store a map (i.e a `Mat` object or something similar with a similar size) where each pixel of the map tells me whether the minimum value was taken from he first or the second image
(You can consider them as n*m*2 image where I want to take the minimum value channel-wise, and want to be able to tell from which channel I got this value).

Is there an easy way to do this in OpenCV?

btw, It's for an Android app, so Java answers are preferred over C++. thanks.

EDIT: I can think of some looping solution for that, but I need my solution to be as efficient as possible, so I wanted to see if there's some built-in function

**EDIT2** - I did not look for a solution where I get the absolute min/max value of the *whole* matrix - I wanted it pixel-wise, including a map which tells me from which image the value was chosen. For example:

```
A = [1 2 ;
     3 4 ]
B = [5 6 ;
     1 2 ]

-->
min(A,B) = [1 2 ;
            1 2 ]
// these are the actual values ^


minInd(A,B) = [1 1 ;
               2 2 ]
// these are the indices ^ where 1 means it was taken from A, and 2 means it was taken from B
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [min and max in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559146/min-and-max-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: my original answer was useless

How about

```
MatExpr min(const Mat& a, const Mat& b)
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504453/elementwise-minimum-of-two-images-in-c-using-opencv) post. If you start with original images `A` and `B` and `C=min(A,B)`, then you could define `D=A-C`. If `D(i,j)==0`, then the value originates from `A`. If `D(i,j)>0`, then the pixel-value originates from `B`.

If `A` and `B` hold floats and not ints then you'd have to do the comparisons with some small tolerance, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I already encountered this answer - Isn't it gives me the min-max location of the total maxuimum-minimum (i.e for the largest/smallest element in the *whole* matrix)? Because I want to know for *each* pixel where it came from, so that won't help me..

Comment: so sorry, I should have finished reading your whole question.... Shouldn't have marked the question as duplicate either....    [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504453/elementwise-minimum-of-two-images-in-c-using-opencv) partially answers your question but doesn't give you the information about which array the data came from....

Comment: changed answer, hope it helps now